# Re-populate dynamic generated checkbox if it fails in validation in an edit form in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox, repopulation

I try form validation in codeigniter.
how Re-populate checkbox which value come from database if it fails in validation in an edit form in Codeigniter.OR
How

```js
<tr>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php if(!empty($mid)){echo $movie1['title'];}elseif(validation_errors()){echo set_value('title'); } ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Genre</td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    if(!empty($mid))
                    {
                        $g=explode(",",$movie1['genre']);
                    }
                    foreach($genre as $getd)
                    {
                        echo"<input type='checkbox' name='genre[]'";
                        if(!empty($mid))
                        {
                              if(in_array($getd['name'],$g)) 
                                { 
                                    echo"checked='checked' ";
                                }
                        }   
                       echo"value='".$getd['name']."'>".$getd['name'];                       
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Re-populate dynamic generated checkbox if it fails in validation in an edit form in Codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this statement after value attribute show the correct code.

if(validation_errors()){echo set_checkbox('genre[]', $getd['name']);}

```js
<tr>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php if(!empty($mid)){echo $movie1['title'];}elseif(validation_errors()){echo set_value('title'); } ?>"></td>
                <td><?php echo form_error('title'); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Genre</td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    if(!empty($mid))
                    {
                        $g=explode(",",$movie1['genre']);
                    }
                    foreach($genre as $getd)
                    {                      
//                     echo form_checkbox('genre[]',$getd['name'],set_checkbox('genre[]', $getd['name'])).$getd['name'];
                        echo"<input type='checkbox' name='genre[]'";
                        if(!empty($mid))
                        {
                              if(in_array($getd['name'],$g)) 
                                { 
                                    echo"checked='checked' ";
                                }
                        }   
                       echo"value='".$getd['name']."'";
                       if(validation_errors()){echo set_checkbox('genre[]', $getd['name']);}
                       echo ">".$getd['name']; 
                       
                    }                
                    
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo form_error('genre[]'); ?></td>
            </tr>
```